# Use my own classes in a servlet (Java/Tomcat/Linux)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, javac

For the last 3 days I couldn't find a single answer for this problem. I need to be able to use my own classes in my servlets.

I am pretty sure that my files hierarchy is correct:

```
|-WEB-INF/
|---classes/
|------com/
|---------myProject/
|------------user/
|---------------User.java
|---------------Location.java
|---------------Comment.java
|------------servlet/
|---------------DoComment.java
```

Since User.java, Location.java and Comment.java are defined in one package as `com.myProject.user` I know I should go to the main root of the java project and compile them this way:

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes$ sudo javac com/myProject/user/Location.java
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes$ sudo javac com/myProject/user/User.java
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes$ sudo javac com/myProject/user/Comment.java
```

However, `javac` cannot identify the other objects (`cannot find symbol` error) when I use a classpath in my compilation.

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes$ sudo javac -cp /usr/share/tomcat6/lib/servlet-api.jar com/myProject/servlet/DoComment.java
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

I created a JAR file for the `com.myProject.user` package and saved it in the `WEB-INF/lib`. Than I compiled the servlet using two classpath seperated by a colon.

Here is the code:

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes$ sudo jar cvf myproject-user.jar com/myProject/user/User.class com/myProject/user/Location.class com/myProject/user/Comment.class
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes$ mv myproject-user.jar ../lib/myproject-user.jar
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes$ sudo service tomcat6 restart
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes$ sudo javac -cp /usr/share/tomcat6/lib/servlet-api.jar:../lib/myproject-user.jar com/myProject/servlet/DoComment.java
```

Thank you [durron597](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768232/durron597) and [kwikness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492348/kwikness) your answers combined was the correct answer.
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

From the javac manpage:

> **-cp** *classpath*
>         Sets  the user class path, overriding the user class path in the CLASSPATH environment
>         variable.  If neither CLASSPATH or -class-
>         path  is  specified, the user class path consists of the current
>         directory.

Basically, you are overriding the classpath when you use the -cp flag, so you need to make sure you specify ALL the required classes in your classpath. The delimiter for classpath entries is a `:` and it takes wildcards.

Comment: The classpath syntax is OS-dependent. On Unix-likes the delimiter is : (colon, not semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

You're putting java source in a location where compiled java classes are expected. Try compiling the source and then adding the class files (.class vs .java) where you're putting them currently.

For this to work, you'd have to be sure that the classes have no dependencies and that the package declaration of your classes match up with the folder hierarchy you're placing them under.

Even so, this generally isn't how web projects are put together. You would be better off packaging the classes into a JAR and placing the JAR in your WEB-INF/lib folder.

For more information on creating a JAR, check this out: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html